# Spring json mapping using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to convert the json string from the request body to the POJO in my controller.

So, for example:
Request:

```
{ "someToken" : "23434" }
```

POJO:

```
class SomeForm {
  @NotNull
  private Long someToken;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController {
  @RequestMapping
  public String makeRequest(@Valid SomeForm someForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
     return someSuccessOrErrorCodesInJsonFormat;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, if the data being sent is correct.
Everything works as it supposed to work, if the data is null, ie bindingResult object contains an error about that.

But if the data is incorrect, ie there will be some letters instead of digits in JSON,
json converter will throw an exception, so server will respond with 500 http response code and some html with exception's stack trace.

I understand, that converter and binder work as follows:
1) Converter makes an object from the json ( here exception occurs )
2) Binder checks the object agains annotations

Is it possible to change the behaviour of the json converter?
For example, if it cannot convert a field, it will leave it as null, instead of throwing an exception?

Basically, I need for a request like:

```
{ "someToken" : "asdfasdf" }
```

to have a constructed SomeForm object with the someToken = null and controller's method called with that object.

Can you suggest me something?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll have to write your own `HttpMessageConverter`. `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` uses Jackson underneath. The `ObjectMapper` cannot be configured to put `null` for an un-deserializable value.